# Routing in MVC Core 2.0.0 with Tag helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Mvc Core 2 has a bug that we cannot use page keyword 
so i changed it to pageid now that bug is fixed but I have a new bug

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: null,
                template: "Community/Page{pageID}",
                defaults: new { Controller = "Forum", action = "Home" });
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Forum}/{action=Home}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: null,
                template: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "Forum", action = "Home", pageID = 1 });
            routes.MapRoute(name: null, template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
```

and my tag helper

```
[HtmlAttributeName(DictionaryAttributePrefix = "page-url-")]
  public Dictionary<string, object> pageUrlValues { set; get; }
  public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
  {
    pageUrlValues["page"] = i;
```

I should get

> url/Community/Page5

but what i get is

> url/Community/Page1?page=5

this works fine but makes my mapping useless
and if i changed page in tag helper to pageID  the page's id now updated as expected to page5 / page4 etc but the content of these pages doesn't update only the content of page1 get displayed

Answer (score 0):

Try to change {pageID} to {page}

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: null,
                template: "Community/Page{page}",
                defaults: new { Controller = "Forum", action = "Home" });
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Forum}/{action=Home}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: null,
                template: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "Forum", action = "Home", pageID = 1 });
            routes.MapRoute(name: null, template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
```

Comment: Thanks but i mentioned in my post that there's a bug in MVC Core 2.0.0 that forbid us to use page keyword and it will be fixed in future releases.
meanwhile i'm looking for an alternative way to fix it.
for some reason this bug in 2.0.0 will be looking for view in shared folder only if we used page

Comment: Keep the same route & change to `pageUrlValues["pageID"] = i;`

Comment: i mentioned that when i do that when i click on pages the content of these pages doesn't update

Comment: for some reason it's not passing the id to my controller

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that i forgot to update the controller's parameter page to pageid